# Github get the results based on date using curl

Tags: curl, github, github-api

When I using

```
curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=python+created:>2009-04-11&+page=2 -otest.
```

its giving a Error.
I get the error-'page' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

when I try the same command on browser

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=python+created:>2009-04-11&+page=2

it works. Can you please correct me what is the issue with the curl command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the URL inside quotes:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=python+created:>2009-04-11&+page=2" -otest.
```

`>` and `&` have special meaning in the shell.